# Pipeline does not complete transition from READY to PAUSED

Tags: gstreamer

I am working with a pipeline that should play a file and, at the same time, produce a scaled version for other purposes (hence the appsink).

The pipeline is the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location=a.mp4 ! decodebin ! tee name=fork 
   fork. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink 
   fork. ! queue ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=180 ! x264enc ! appsink
```

and does not completes the transition from READY to PAUSED. It completes the transition (and then plays correctly by moving to PLAYING) if I do one of the following:

1. Remove one of the two branches exiting from tee (so x264enc alone works)
2. Remove the x264enc element from the branch heading to appsink.

Here there is a graph with a pipeline very close to the one above that shows the same problem. The 'guilty' element is the appsink that is still in the READY->PAUSED transition, but I cannot see any reason for that. By the way if I remove the x264enc from the appsink branch it works!

Why?
[image: Pipeline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the option `tune=zerolatency` for the `x264enc` element. Alternatively increase the `queue` sizes after the `tee`. The reason for this is that `x264enc` in its default configuration has a higher latency than the default `queue` size. E.g. it consumes more than the other `queue` path can hold before it produces any data. So the two branches deadlock each other and cannot preroll.

Comment: tune=zerolatency works, I have tried to enlarge queues well over default but with no result.

Comment: Note that queue have three different properties for max sizes. The quick and dirty you can try is to add one or more queues: `.. ! queue ! queue ! queue ! ..`. Just make sure you get the right path - should be the rendering path, not the encoder path. When in doubt do it for both.