# With gstreamer tee element, pre-roll is not completing

Tags: gstreamer

In the below example pipeline,

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc num-buffers=100 ! "video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1, format=NV12" ! videoscale ! "video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=NV12" ! tee name=t ! queue ! fakesink t. ! queue !  x264enc rc-lookahead=5 ! fakesink

The pipeline is not completing the pre-roll, async-done message is not reaching the gst-launch-1.0

This works only with "async=false". But why is this required, why is it not working without "async=false"  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipeline does not complete transition from READY to PAUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403296/pipeline-does-not-complete-transition-from-ready-to-paused)

Comment: Yes its the same issue. But my question is, even if x264enc consumes more data than of the queue size to produce the first output frame, videotestsrc is ready push more data into the queue. In fact, if I put a queue after videotestsrc, it will be full when the hang happens.

Comment: The queues after the tee are relevant.. because queue does not copy buffers, it references buffer and hand it to both paths. So they block each other. Whatever you have before the queue is not relevant.

Comment: I am not convinced here. Let me explain my question in detail.
                                     
videotestsrc - > tee name=t t. ->   queue_1 -> fakesink_1 t. -> queue_2 -> x264enc -> fakesink_2

Now first buffer coming in queue_1 path will reach fakesink_1 and wait for preroll, but x264enc (which is in queue_2 path) cannot produce output for the first input buffer, it produces only after the GOP. Now tee blocks on queue_1 because this path is waiting for preroll to complete hence queue_2 is also blocked.

Comment: Now once "async-done" from fakesink_1 reaches gst-launch and then PLAYING state will be set and then queue_1 will be unblocked and so is queue_2. Then this dead lock should have been release. But its not release.